# Get PHP AST node kind

Tags: php, abstract-syntax-tree

After setting `$ast = ast\parse_code('<?php $a=1;', $version=50);`

I can see the contents of the node but wanted to know exactly what the node type was. The output I can see just gives the integer value of the assigned kind constant - is there a way to find out which kind this refers to (i.e. get the name of the constant)?

```
php > var_dump($ast);
object(ast\Node)#1 (4) {
  ["kind"]=>
  int(132)
  ["flags"]=>
  int(0)
  ["lineno"]=>
  int(1)
  ["children"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(ast\Node)#2 (4) {
      ["kind"]=>
      int(517)
      ["flags"]=>
      int(0)
      ["lineno"]=>
      int(1)
      ["children"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["var"]=>
        object(ast\Node)#3 (4) {
          ["kind"]=>
          int(256)
          ["flags"]=>
          int(0)
          ["lineno"]=>
          int(1)
          ["children"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(1) "a"
          }
        }
        ["expr"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser? It has much more clear object-based API, that is easy to extend and work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type of node you are looking for, you can compare against a given kind, i.e.

```
$node->kind === \ast\AST_ASSIGN
```

For general name lookup, however, the library provides `ast\get_kind_name()` ([source](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast/blob/master/ast.c#L909)). For example:

```
php > echo \ast\get_kind_name(517);
AST_ASSIGN
```

If you would like an easier way to view the AST, the library provides a `util.php` file ([source](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast/blob/4e5d7833f547995ca1462362108ab7f161796cba/util.php)) with a function that dumps out the AST. Details on using it can be found below the first example in [this section](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast#example) (copied here).

```
require 'path/to/util.php';
echo ast_dump(ast\parse_code('<?php $a=1;', $version=50)), "\n";
```

Comment: get_kind_name and ast_dump were what I was looking for. Thanks